# how to subscribe to valueChange of radio button group using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

Here my template:

```
      <mat-radio-group 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedHistoryType"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        (ngModelChange)="setValue($event)">
      <mat-radio-button value="1">Customer</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="2">Internal</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

I need to be listening the change on radio buttons value and I would like to subscribe an observable which would be listening the changes for me.

Here my .ts so far:

```
  setValue(selectedHistoryType) {
   console.log(selectedHistoryType)
  }
```

I can console.log the value but I would need to be listening the value change thanks to an observable in order to use it later to combine with other observables using rxjs operators. Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this (or any form in my opinion) with ngModel. That is old school Angular v1 way of doing things.

Use reactive forms.

component snippet

```
form: FormGroup;
private readonly unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    selectedHistoryType: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form.selectedHistoryType.valueChanges
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged(isEqual), takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe(selectedHistory: any => {
     console.log('value changed', selectedHistory);
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.unsubscribed$.next();
  this.unsubscribed$.complete();
}
```

HTML snippet

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <mat-radio-group [formControl]="selectedHistoryType">
      <mat-radio-button value="1">Customer</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="2">Internal</mat-radio-button>
 </mat-radio-group> 
</form>
```

isEqual is a lodash library that when combined with distinctUntilChanged from rxJS will prevent re-trigger if same value is selected twice.  takeUntil will prevent memory leaks when combined with ngOndestroy.

And since you mentioned need to use this in other rxJs functions....your REALLY want a reactive form and not the old way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks, but my idea is establish two-ways data binding in order to be able to change from template and from the server value. Thats why I am trying to use ngModel

Comment: You can do all that from reactive forms as well. In fact, it is far easier and requires you to write less code.

https://www.calibraint.com/blog/angular-forms

Comment: In fact, since you state you want to use this with ngRx (aka RxJS) operators, adding template-driven forms to the mix is incorrect architecture in my opinion. https://www.codemotion.com/magazine/dev-hub/web-developer/rxjs-and-angular-reactive-forms/